# How to get all emails within the organization?

Tags: email, user-record, app-development, app

I'm making an application that needs to retrieve all the emails in the organization. Currently, I only get the email of one particular person, i.e. the one who install's the application. How do I get **everyone's email**?

Edit:

So for example:

if John, Bob, and Mark all work in the same organization and John installs it, I know how to get his email. But I also want Bob and Mark's email.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you looking for the Email address of every User or Contact?

Comment: every user in the organization on which the application was installed.

Comment: Could you post some code or the method you're currently using to obtain the installer's email? Its difficult to help someone without knowing where they're starting from. Also, are the emails related to anything like Accts, Opps, Cases, etc?

Answer (score -1):

In salesforce we have a method call post installer class. Which execute once user install the application. You can write the code into that calss to get email id of organization.

Thanks,
Piyush parmar

Comment: Thats not what he's asking ?